# Load From JSON in Canvas without Clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvas, fabricjs

I want to Add object in my existing canvas from JSON string without clearing existing objects. But when I click button to add it clears my canvas and then add from json string.
Please help me how can I do this ?
Below is what I have tried

```
var yourData = '[{"type":"group","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":161.82,"top":76.48,"width":174.38,"height":59.05,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","objects":[{"type":"line","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":0,"top":-0.01,"width":172.38,"height":1,"fill":"transparent","stroke":"transparent","strokeWidth":2,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","x1":75.6300048828125,"y1":75.98500061035156,"x2":248.00997924804687,"y2":75.98500061035156},{"type":"rect","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-86.19,"top":-30.03,"width":172.38,"height":59.05,"fill":"yellow","stroke":"red","strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":0.3,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","rx":0,"ry":0,"x":0,"y":0}]}]';
var json = '{"objects":' + yourData + '}';

canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), function(o, object) {
  fabric.log(o, object);
});
```

Comment: There is no "loadFromJSON" method on canvas elements.

Comment: but its working ....only thing is clearing whole canvas and then adding json string

Comment: @JohnWick, next time, remember to include the library you do use in your question directly (I've done it by including the proper tag here).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas/Fabric.js .loadFromJSON() replaces entire canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972454/canvas-fabric-js-loadfromjson-replaces-entire-canvas)

Comment: I will remember next time ....apart from loadFromJSON what we can use

Comment: Well in the dupe I linked to, OP saw that he should have used `fromObject` method. I'm not a fabric guru, but when we fix the fiddle posted by OP, this seems to work  : http://jsfiddle.net/sFGGV/30/

Comment: FromObject worked at my place too .....thanxxx can we make selectable but not movable for added object only

Comment: Just set `"lockMovementY"` and `"lockMovementX"` to `true` in your json objects : I did it on the hand http://jsfiddle.net/sFGGV/31/

Comment: its working ......how to make it selected object programmatically ?